# Select rows from a table, ignore rows until a field value is encountered

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.2

Let's say I have a table that contains information about user savings to a thrift society and the assessment of each deposit type as *good* or *bad* based on internal logic. How do I select rows from this table so that all preceding rows to the last **good** row are skipped per user?

**Before**

```
id     | user |type | amount
----------------------------
20     | 98   | good | 40
35     | 98   | bad  | 30
62     | 98   | good | 20
89     | 98   | bad  | 60
93     | 98   | bad  | 10
100    | 99   | good | 20
103    | 99   | good | 22
109    | 99   | good | 220
121    | 99   | bad  | 640
193    | 99   | bad  | 110
```

I would like to ignore all records for a user until the last **good** row is encountered, then subsequent rows can be counted. The rows are ordered by increasing **id**s which are not consecutive.

**After**

```
id     | user |type | amount
----------------------------
62     | 98   | good | 20
89     | 98   | bad  | 60
93     | 98   | bad  | 10
100    | 99   | good | 220
121    | 99   | bad  | 640
193    | 99   | bad  | 110
```

Comment: . . If there are no "good" rows, what do you want returned?

Comment: No rows are fine if there are no good rows.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to a query that returns the maximum id for each user with `type = 'good'`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select user, max(id) id
  from tablename
  where type = 'good'
  group by user
) tt on tt.user = t.user and tt.id <= t.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpPUbqrZQ1HS1zUPQwf9Zv/0).
Results:

```
| id  | user | type | amount |
| --- | ---- | ---- | ------ |
| 62  | 98   | good | 20     |
| 89  | 98   | bad  | 60     |
| 93  | 98   | bad  | 10     |
| 109 | 99   | good | 220    |
| 121 | 99   | bad  | 640    |
| 193 | 99   | bad  | 110    |
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id >= (select max(t2.id)
               from t t2
               where t2.user = t.user and t2.type = 'good'
              );
```

This should have good performance if you have an index on `(user, type, id)`.

Based on the phrasing of your question, I am interpreting it as requiring at least one good row.  If this is not the case, then the following logic can be used:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id >= all (select t2.id
                   from t t2
                   where t2.user = t.user and t2.type = 'good'
                  );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when type = 'good' then id end) over (partition by user) as max_good_id
      from t
     ) t
where id >= max_good_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `MariaDB 10.2+`, Window Analytic Functions might be used such as

`SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`

```
WITH  T2 AS
(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY id DESC) AS sum,
       T.*
  FROM T     
)
SELECT id, user, type, amount
  FROM T2
 WHERE ( type = 'good' AND sum = 1 )  OR ( type != 'good' AND sum = 0 )
 ORDER BY id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7b31f6fd56f8e29fa698b8b423abed53)</kbd>